# Raspberry Pi as an Upscaller

Tags: analog-to-digital

I have been looking at better ways of playing my old NES/SNES on modern TV's via HDMI. I like the old hardware, I like the controllers and I like hunting down the cartridges so have little interest in emulation.

One option is an XRGB-mini framemeister which upscales with very low latency (approx 20ms) and does some nice other bits like adding scanlines. The issue is, it costs the best part of £200.

Would it even be possible to build a low-cost, low-latency upscaller using a Pi?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely not going to work. As your consoles use composite video which is analogue, there is no easy way to read it in directly with GPIOs. Furthermore Linux isn't that well suited for realtime tasks because of it's multithreaded nature. If you are still interested in building a solution yourself, maybe this site can help you: http://www.techmind.org/vd/vidmk2.html

Probably you could connect the stuff that is described there to the PI and then construct and upscale an image and display it via HDMI. But as your main concern seems to be latency, this would probably not be a viable option. Maybe a solution using some kind of FPGA could work but that would neither be easy nor cheap (although I don't know much about this technology).

TLDR: It is not possible.